# Are there any disadvantages to using READ UNCOMMITTED transaction level if the database is set to READ_ONLY?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Our scenario is as follows: We have a database that we plan to fill during the night and set to read_only when the ETL is complete. Will it then be safe to use READ_UNCOMMITED for the connections?

Comment: I don't see why if could be unsafe ...

Comment: Well yes, not sure why you would bother though. There won't be any uncommited to read.

Comment: So, SQL Server will never place locks on transactions against a database if it is read_only?

Comment: imho,If those tables are not part of concurrent DML operation then there is no harm.Also id there is no harm in reading few dirty records.Also READ_UNCOMMITED is fast .Anybody please comment,if I am wrong .

Answer (score 0):

Read uncommited is usually dangerous for applications since dirty reads are allowed, so one transaction may see not-yet-committed changes made by other transactions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Read_uncommitted)

In your specific case is necessary a study of the purpose of your application. There is a problem if your clients see uncommited data? Subsequent queries can not bring the same result, this will be a problem?

Comment: If the database is read-only, there will never be any uncommitted data because it's impossible to commit any changes to the database.

Comment: If you have connections while the ETL is running you may see uncommitted data. But if your plan is to access the database only after the ETL is complete there is no problem.